# Why can't my project in Apache Netbeans 12.5 be run using JDK 17?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-12, java-17

I am using Apache NetBeans 12.5 with JDK 17.0.1.

When I run my project it can't be run, as you can see from this screen shot:

[image: NetBeans screen shot]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

One of the notifications in your screen shot (*"Install nb-javac Library"*) indicates the probable cause of your problems. To fix that you need to install the *nb-javac* library:

- Select **Tools > Options > Java > GUI Builder**
- Your **Options** window will look similar to this if the *nb-javac* plugin is not installed:
  [image: Options window]
- You don't need to do anything beyond opening that tab to provoke the NetBeans Installer to invite you to install the *nb-javac* plugin:
  [image: Installnbjavac]
- click **Next >** and complete the wizard to install the *nb-javac* plugin.
- No restart of NetBeans is required to ensure that the plugin has been installed successfully. Just navigate to **Tools > Plugins > Installed** and check for the presence of an entry labeled "*The nb-javac Java editing support library*":

  [image: Installed plugins]
- Finally, verify that you can now run your project.

If you still have problems after installing *nb-javac* then click the "*Unexpected Exception*" entry in the **Notifications** window (as shown in your screen shot), and update your question with the extra details NetBeans provides.